# How write a javascript variable in window.open function

Tags: javascript, php

```
<script>
 var1 = "http://ofuran.com";
 var2 = "?ref=Df34hfgT"; var newlink = var1.concat(var2);
</script>
```

How I use this newlink variable in the following line? please help me by doing.

```
<?php echo '<script>window.open("http://www.ofuran.com", "_blank"); </script>'; ?>
```

Comment: why do you use php when the variable is in javascript? You can simply use <script>window.open(newlink, "_blank"); </script>

Comment: Maybe he's trying to bypass Cloudflare?

Comment: @ALMaMun it solved your problem?

Comment: No @Forbs I  just try to redirect with a new reference.

Comment: Yes @Rinsad Ahmed. Solved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the code:

```
<script>
    var1 = "http://ofuran.com";
    var2 = "?ref=Df34hfgT";
    var newlink = var1.concat(var2);

</script>


<?php echo '<script>window.open(newlink, "_blank"); </script>'; ?>
```

Comment: Why do you need PHP to use JS variables? And please highlight the differences, such that the OP can see it clearly and learn from it

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this way,

```js
var var1 = "http://ofuran.com";
var var2 = "?ref=Df34hfgT";
var newlink = var1.concat(var2);
window.open(newlink, "_blank");
```

Comment: @ALMaMun glat it works for you :). By the way plz have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers